# Create a callback function with another callback inside

Tags: kotlin

My apologies for the bad title, I'm fairly new to callbacks and I'm not sure how to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a class called `MyClass` that has a function `connectToService` inside of it.

The function `connectToService` does some calculations and then calls a function with a callback, like this:

```
fun connectToService() {
  //Whatever calculations
  val a = 7
  var b = 3
  var c = a + b

  val token = MyToken()
  token.actionCallback = object: SuperSecretObject {
    override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: MyToken) {
      c++
    }
    override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: MyToken) {
      c--
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create another class, `YourClass` which creates an object of `MyClass` and then calls the `connectToService` function. When the `connectToService` function finishes either the `onSuccess` or `onFailure`functions, I want to do something depending on which one was triggered (something different each time, thats why I can't put it inside the `onSuccess` or `onFailure` blocks of code).

Something like this:

```
//Inside `yourClass`
private fun myFunc() {
  val yourClassObj = YourClass()

  youClassObj.connectToService {
    if(onSuccess)
      reinventTheWheel()
    else
      squareIt()
  }

  youClassObj.connectToService {
    combAWatermelon()
  }

  youClassObj.connectToService {
    sharpenMyHammer()
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it? If it's not, what would be the closest solution to this requirement?

EDIT:

More detailed information has been requested, so while I can't provide exact details, I'll do my best to explain what's going on.

I'm basically working on a library to simplify petitions. For example, MQTT petitions. This is something tht resembles what I want to achieve:

```
/**
 * Subscribes to a list of topics and handles the results
 */
fun subscribe(client: MqttAndroidClient, list: MutableList<String>, onMsg: ((String, MqttMessage)->Unit)?=null, conLost: ((Throwable)->Unit)?=null, delComp: ((IMqttDeliveryToken)->Unit)?=null) {
    if (client.isConnected) { //Assert connection
        for(x in list.iterator()) { //Subscribe to events
            client.subscribe(x, 0)
        }

        client.setCallback(object : MqttCallback {
            override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable) { //Lost connection
                Log.i("TAG", "Connection lost")
                conLost?.let { it(cause) }
            }

            @Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)
            override fun messageArrived(topic: String, message: MqttMessage) { //Arrived message
                Log.i("TAG", "Message arrived: topic => $topic, message => $message")
                onMsg?.let { it(topic, message) }
            }

            override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken) { //Delivery complete
                Log.i("TAG", "Delivery complete")
                delComp?.let { it(token) }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The `messageArrived` function must have a behaviour that can be customized depending on the app it's being used on.

For example, on one app I want the `onMsg()` function to be like this:

```
when(topic) {
    "firstTopic" -> {
        localVariable++
    }
    "secondTopic" -> {
        localMethod()
    }
    "thirdTopic" -> {
        localClass.variable.method()
    }
}
```

If I'm using it on an Android device, I'd like to be able to update the interface, doing Android API calls, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your question correctly. I think what you are looking for is passing lambdas.

```
fun connectToService(onSucc: ()->Unit, onFail: ()->Unit) {
  //Whatever calculations

  MyToken().actionCallback = object: SuperSecretObject {
    override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: MyToken) {
      onSucc()
    }
    override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: MyToken) {
      onFail()
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
connectToService({ /* Something */ }, { /* Something else */ })
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, however I'm not sure how it would work. If one of the functions (onSucc() or onFail()) needs to acces a variable that is located on the `YourClass` class, would it be able to access it?

Comment: You have to pass it. For example you type `onSucc: (String)->Unit` instead of `()->Unit)` and later on you can do `onSucc("Something")`. I'd suggest you to read more about lambda functions online: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Comment: If that's the case, the solution wont work. onSucc() will have to use a lot of diferent variables and functions from `yourClass` and I don't see passing them one by one as a viable option. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Pass the whole instance of your class maybe? Like `onSucc: (YourClass)->Unit`? I don't know. If you give me a more solid example I can refine my answer even further.

Comment: I meant more info about your implementation, not about your project. It's still hard to tell, but you probably need something like that `onMsg: YourClass.(String, MqttMessage)->Unit`, so the lambda has access to your class' instance. The other ways is as I described above, you pass the instance as an argument. Also, please avoid using nullables, for a cleaner and safer code.